# Prisma executeRaw batch operation save incorrectly Float values

Tags: prisma, prisma2

does anyone have some bad experience with saving float via executeRaw batch operation? Or at least an idea of how to solve my problem: ExecuteRaw is saving numbers like 7.76e-322. Input is 157 and saved value is 7.76e-322.

```js
  const items = [{uniqueId: 1, price: 100},{uniqueId: 2, price: 200}];
  const completeKeys: string[] = Object.keys(items[0]);

  const updateFieldsMapper = (item: any) => {
    return Prisma.sql`(${Prisma.join(
      completeKeys.map((key: string) => item[key])
    )})`;
  };

  const insertKeys = completeKeys.map((key) =>
    key.toLocaleLowerCase() !== key ? `"${key}"` : `${key}`
  );
  let insertValues = completeKeys.map((item) => updateFieldsMapper(item));
  
  const updateSet = completeKeys.reduce((updateSet: string[], key: string) => {
    if (!ingnoredKeys.includes(key)) {
      updateSet.push(`"${key}" = EXCLUDED."${key}"`);
    }
    return updateSet;
  }, []);

  try {
    await prisma.$executeRaw`
      INSERT INTO "Product"  (${Prisma.raw(insertKeys.join(","))})
      VALUES ${Prisma.join(insertValues)}
      ON CONFLICT (uniqueId)
      DO UPDATE SET ${Prisma.raw(updateSet.join(","))};`;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(util.inspect(error, false, null, true));
    Sentry.captureException(error);
  }
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Is there any loss of precision on the floats?

Comment: There isn't any loss. I'm saving for example 156 and instead in a database, there is 7.76e-322. If I use the same values just in a simple prisma.product.update, all works well and number 156 is stored.

Comment: It would be great if you could create an issue [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new?assignees=&labels=kind%2Fbug&template=bug_report.yml) mentioning the above query.

Comment: Prisma issue added: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/9195